# Discord.py YT-DLP Download Playlist one by one

Tags: python, discord.py, yt-dlp

I have a little problem and cannot solve it. It might be just a little trick or something.

I want to code a music bot for discord. It should also play playlists.
It works but YT-DLP always downloads the whole Playlist first.

I cannot figure out, that YT-DLP downloads it one by one.

My Code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import yt_dlp as youtube_dl
import asyncio

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True  # needed for your bot
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)


ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': 'downloads/%(extractor)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': False,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': True,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': False,
    'no_warnings': False,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0',
    'force-ipv4': True,
    'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
    'cachedir': False
}
playlist_queue = []
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name}')

@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, url):
    try:
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel  # checking if user is in a voice channel
    except AttributeError:
        return await ctx.send(
            "Du bist in keinem Sprachkanal. Bitte geh in einen Sprachkanal!")  # member is not in a voice channel

    permissions = voice_channel.permissions_for(ctx.me)
    if not permissions.connect or not permissions.speak:
        await ctx.send("Ich hab keine Berechtigungen zu sprechen oder dem Sprachkanal beizutreten.")
        return

    voice_client = ctx.guild.voice_client
    if not voice_client:
        await voice_channel.connect()
        voice_client = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice_client.is_playing():
        voice_client.stop()
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=True)
        if 'entries' in info:  # Prüfen, ob es sich um eine Playlist handelt
            for entry in info['entries']:
                url2 = f"downloads/youtube-{entry['id']}.webm"  # Pfad zur heruntergeladenen Datei
                playlist_queue.append(url2)  # Füge das Lied zur Warteschlange hinzu
        else:
            url2 = f"downloads/youtube-{info['id']}.webm"
        voice_client.stop()
        voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url2))


@bot.command()
async def skip(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.voice_client
    if voice_client.is_playing():
        voice_client.stop()

    # Überspringe das aktuelle Lied in der Warteschlange
    if playlist_queue:
        next_song = playlist_queue.pop(0)
        voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(next_song))


@bot.command()
async def repeat(ctx, url):
    try:
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel  # checking if user is in a voice channel
    except AttributeError:
        return await ctx.send(
            "Du bist in keinem Sprachkanal. Bitte geh in einen Sprachkanal!")  # member is not in a voice channel

    permissions = voice_channel.permissions_for(ctx.me)
    if not permissions.connect or not permissions.speak:
        await ctx.send("Ich hab keine Berechtigungen zu sprechen oder dem Sprachkanal beizutreten.")
        return

    voice_client = ctx.guild.voice_client
    if not voice_client:
        await voice_channel.connect()
        voice_client = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice_client.is_playing():
        voice_client.stop()

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=True)
        if 'entries' in info:  # Prüfen, ob es sich um eine Playlist handelt
            url2 = f"downloads/youtube-{info['entries'][0]['id']}.webm"
        else:
            url2 = f"downloads/youtube-{info['id']}.webm"
        while True:
            voice_client.stop()
            voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url2))
            while voice_client.is_playing():
                await asyncio.sleep(1)

@bot.command()
async def pause(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.voice_client
    if voice_client.is_playing():
        voice_client.pause()


@bot.command()
async def resume(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.voice_client
    if voice_client.is_paused():
        voice_client.resume()


@bot.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.voice_client
    if voice_client.is_connected():
        await voice_client.disconnect()


bot.run('*not for public eyes*')
```

Can you guys help me?

Thank you!

Best regards,

Leon

Comment: Please note that you should always provide a [mre] - emphasis on *minimal*, as most of the code here seems irrelevant to the question.

Comment: `yt-dlp --flat-playlist --get-id <url of the list>` will give you the ids of all videos in the playlist. `yt-dlp --flat-playlist --get-id --get-title <...>` will also give you the titles